# rails server working on one project but not other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making my second Ruby project, just learning here but when I create a new rails project and then go inside of the folder and type

```
rails server
```

I get this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
  dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9):
  Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in 'require'
from /Users/memin/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in 'tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
from script/rails:6:in 'require'
from script/rails:6
```

It is odd because I have a different project that runs fine but this error has me dumbfounded.

Comment: I found the answer in a different question. Apparently this magic command fixes it    sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Answer (score 0):

I have spent no less than 3 hours working on this problem---after no less than 4 "solutions", here is the permanent solution to the problem, at least for me. Everything works now. You're almost there!! Don't give up!
put this bit of code in your .profile and .bash_profile files. If you don't know how to do that, type this in the terminal every time you open it...
`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

**** OK, OK, this is what my .bash_profile looks like:
`alias ll="ls -lahG"
alias whereami="pwd"`

export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/my$
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

To edit your bash, in the root ($) terminal menu, type in "`ls -la`", then type in `nano .bash_profile` and/or `nano .profile` to get into the menu. Once you're done with editing, hit ctrl-X, then 'return' to get back to the main menu, so to speak. good luck!